# Type annotated sortedset in python

Tags: python, types, annotations

I have a project which uses SortedSet from [sortedcontainers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/).

```
# Snip
self.adj_list  = dict(zip(range(self.noNodes), [SortedSet([]) for i in range(self.noNodes)]))
# Snip

for (u, v) in graph:
    self.adj_list[u].add(v)
    self.adj_list[v].add(u)
# Snip
def get_intersection(self, u: int, v:int) -> List[int]:
    return list(self.adj_list[u].intersection(self.adj_list[v]))
# Snip
def update(self, edge : Tuple[int, int], val : float) -> None:
    self.adj_list[u].add(v)
    self.adj_list[v].add(u)
# Snip
```

I am facing performance issues with my project and wanted to speed it up. I was planning on adding typeannotations to the project and use mypy.
From what I understand sortedcontainers has an open PR to add type annotations to sortedcontainers library. I was wondering is there a way around type annotations here or any better library that I can use for the same?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit: The main error that I am currently facing trying to run mypy and mypyc is the sortedcontainers library. Is there a well performant balanced binary search that I could use for the sorted set data structures.

Comment: Type annotations alone don't speed up your code. (You might try using `mypyc`, which is a project that compiles Python source to native executable code, using type hints to guide optimizations.)

Comment: This is my first project using mypy. So pardon my lack of knowledge. What happens if a library does not have nootations? Can I skip the library from performance improvements when transpiling (I am not sure if transpiling is the right word either) with mypyc ?

Comment: As far as I know, `mypyc` will do the best it can in the absence of type hints, but it's also mostly an experimental project at this time. For the most part, type hints are for checking *correctness* of your code, not improving its performance.